# Where is coming uninstalled language in Windows7 from?

Tags: windows-7

Suddenly i have in the language bar a language i haven't ever installed. Look at screenshot: in the system setting there are two languages i set up with own hands, german+russian. Since some days i have suddenly english in the language bar.

How can i get rid of it? It is very annoying - i switch languages often with shortcut and additional language causes many errors.

I'm on Win7x64 Pro.

[image]

**Up**: deep manual registry clean and restart were helpful. I suspect, the cause were leftovers by not correctly uninstalled software. Anyway, for all who is affected: try to clean your registry, OR try to restart on previous restoring point.

Comment: you bin hacked :) - I have never seen extra lang that I don't add; I'm on Win7x64 Pro too for many years while traveling had changed my list of langs many times but never had unwanted item there.

Comment: me too:) thats why i'm out of ideas... But a hack is out of question

Comment: It may have been installed with an update, but you should be able to remove it by clicking on it and pressing **Entfernen**.

Comment: @AFH - as it displayed on screenshot - this language isn't shown in setting, there is nothing to click on and entfernen...

Comment: I was puzzled by that. I can't run many useful checks, since my W7 systems were all upgraded to W10. I'm not sure what your drop-down list is: if it's the keyboard layout, maybe you can find the setting in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language\Language options` as an input method (W10 location, but I can't recall where it was in W7 - was it under Internationalisation?). Otherwise try adding manually, then removing again.

Comment: try to add that lang and then remove

Comment: got the beast - updated the post.